# What's the star icon in eclipse? How to erase them?

Tags: eclipse, git, github, egit

I'm using eclipse4.2.2.I cloned a repository from github and then created a pydev project in the same directory.Here's what the navigator looks like:

[image]

As you see,the star icons and red background color are really annoying.
Could somebody explain what those things are, and how to get rid of them?Thank you!

Comment: See this [Label Documentations](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Label_Decorations) for Egit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're on **Git Repository Exploring** perspective and star means it's a new / modified file (source control wise). In a way this is a helpful extra information to show you which file has changed since last commit

Changing to other perspective might no longer show the stars. Have a look at the perspective switcher (normally at the top right corner)

[image]